# How can I make cURL set a cookie relative to the script?

Tags: php, curl, wamp

**EDIT**: How can I change the relative path to 'relative-to-this-file' mode? Like on my host...

---

I've got a `cURL PHP` script which works. It gets my schedule from my school site. Though there is one strange thing: On my **webhost** it creates the cookie.txt and on my **localhost** it doesn't.

- Why doesn't cURL create a cookie on my localhost? Something with relative paths and wampserver? Maybe some settings on wamp?

I am using:

- WampServer
- Windows 7

cURL does create a cookie if I use: '/cookie.txt' but ofcourse it creates it in my c:/. And that is obviously not where I want it to be. Also I want to prevent using full paths.

Comment: Maybe the account running PHP doesn't have the permission to write to the location you set for the cookie file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

be sure you have these two options in the curl setup phase

```
$cookiefile = dirname(__FILE__)."/cookie.txt" ; 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);
```

they will create a cookie in the folder your script resides in

EDIT : added option to set the cookie in the same dir as the script is running in

Comment: How can I get the cookie to be in my www directory? Is there an appache setting I should change?

Comment: yes @SuperSpy, you could do something like ` $cookiefile = dirname(\_\_FILE\_\_)."/cookie.txt" ; curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookiefile);curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookiefile);` ( this will place the cookie in the same folder as the script is running, you can change accordingly for your desired path)